# Cant find the next element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok my HTML markup is as follows:

```
<div class="refine_search_box"> 
    <div class="heading">Refine Search</div>   

    <div class="section_heading"><a href="#">By Size</a></div>
    <div class="section">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Model.SizeList, "key", "value", Model.Size), "")
    </div>

    <div class="section_heading"><a href="#">By Sport</a></div>
    <div class="section">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Sport, new SelectList(Model.SportList, "key", "value", Model.Sport), "")
    </div>
</div>
```

My Jquery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.section").toggle();

    $(".refine_search_box a").click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $div = $this.prev().nextAll(".section").first();
        $this.toggleClass("selected");
        $div.toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

What I want to happen is when the link in the .section_heading is clicked I want the .section div to open thats directly after it. But my jQuery always returns nothing for $div, I thought this would be quite simple but I'm obviously missing something obvious. I'm very new to jQuery so apologise if its stupidly simple!

Cheers.

Comment: I can't see the class `refine_search_box` in the markup.

Comment: where is `.refine_search_box a` dude..

Comment: Sorry I've added it now missed it when I copied and pasted

Comment: @Chris. Well, replace `.refine_search_box a` with `.section_heading a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use .parent() instead of .prev():

```
$(".refine_search_box a").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $div = $this.parent().next();
    $this.toggleClass("selected");
    $div.toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is assuming that '.refine_search_box' surrounds all of your `section_heading` divs.

You can also just use `.parent().next()` as long as your html stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

- use `next` instead of `nextAll`
- `prev` return the previous sibling, you neef the parent:

---

```
$(".refine_search_box a").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $div = $this.parent().next(".section").first(); //< ====
    $this.toggleClass("selected");
    $div.toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that as I commented, I can't see the `refine_search_box` class in the markup, maybe it should be:

```
    $(".section_heading a").click(function (e) {
        ...
    }
```